# Eclipse Plugin Development - get all repository commits

Tags: eclipse, plugins, pde

I am developing Eclipse plugin. I want to extract all versions (commits) from repository associated with project in current workspace. I am able to get single file versions using `IFileHistoryProvider.getFileHistoryFor(file)` but I have no idea how to get them for entire project. I don't see applicable method in `org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider`.

```
IJavaProject project = JavaCore.create(testProject);
RepositoryProvider provider = RepositoryProvider.getProvider(project.getProject());
```

Having single commit id I want to get its timestamp.
How to do that?

**EDIT**

I think I should rewrite my question.

In my plugin I want to get the history of files in repository (git, svn). The history should be limited by starting and ending commmit. These commits will be defined by the commit ids*.

I can retrieve all files in project, and for every file all revisions. Every revision has its timestamp. I can include or exclude particular revision comparing its timestamp with the starting and ending timestamp. However, I have to get to know these timestamps in some way, having only commit ids*.

I can not find proper method in `org.eclipse.team.core`.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at all the current files in a project with:

```
project.getProject().accept(new IResourceVisitor() {
  @Override
  public boolean visit(IResource resource) throws CoreException
  {
    // TODO your code here
    // IResource may be a file or an IFolder
  }
});
```